# Ansible synchronize module error - no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS ansible version: 2.1.0, the sshport on remote server is 44022

Im using adhoc way to run synchronize module as a sudo user[`nopasswd is not enabled`] to synchronize local and remote directories (push)

Below is host file /etc/ansible/hosts

```
[webdb]
10.153.99.132
10.153.99.52
[webdb:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ctuser
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/root/.ssh/id_rsa
ansible_port=44022
```

Below are the command used:

```
ansible webdb -s -K  -m synchronize -a "src=/tmp/muhan 
dest=/store" -u ctuser
```

and (dest_port used)

```
ansible webdb -s -K  -m synchronize -a "dest_port=44022 
src=/tmp/muhan dest=/store" -u ctuser
```

Both commands outputs below error:-

```
10.153.99.52 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=44022' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/tmp/muhan\" \"ctuser@10.153.99.52:/store\"", 
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "sudo: unable to resolve host c2.example.com\nsudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", 
    "rc": 12
}
10.153.99.132 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=44022' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/tmp/muhan\" \"ctuser@10.153.99.132:/store\"", 
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "sudo: unable to resolve host c1.example.com\nsudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", 
    "rc": 12
}
```

Comment: `-s ` and `-K` are both deprecated. What do you get if you use `-b` and `--ask-become-pass`?

Comment: Also, if you are using key-based authentication it may be ideal to enable passwordless sudo.

Comment: did you figure out a solution?

Comment: No solution .Currently im using with password less sudo

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this from multiple angles:

- disable sudo tty requirement: `sed -i 's/Defaults    requiretty/Defaults    !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers` (this is on all of the nodes you are using Ansible)
- change ansible.cfg to have tty flag for ssh http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args (this is only on the node where you are executing Ansible on)

The exact switches you need:

```
ssh_args = -tt
```

Comment: the remote servers are ubuntu 14.04 and the line "Defaults requiretty" is not present on /etc/sudoers file.I looked at man page and it tells that requiretty is off by default. Can you provide more light on how to give tty flag for ssh with ansible ssh-args ?. currently iam making it work by enabling NOPASSWD on /etc/sudoers for the user. Thanks

Comment: added the `ssh_args = -tt`  but didnt work , it outputs below error `"msg": "sudo: unable to resolve host c1.example.com\nsudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed `